# How to deploy SSRS report with multiple data sources?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have two different databases on two different servers and I need data from both the databases for two different datasets associated with two tables in report.

The problem is I am not allowed to deploy the report from BIDS and report will be deployed by Upload File option in report manager, so how to deploy this report with multiple data sources?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try Report Builder?

Comment: For what purpose I require to try Report Builder?

Comment: Save to the portal with multiple data sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uploading the report to Report Manager, go to the report properties and edit the data sources there. An easy way to get to the report properties page is click Show Details button when you are in Report Manager. Then, just click the properties icon under the Edit column. Either that, or view the report (which should fail to run initially), and click the Properties tab at the top page.

Once you are there, click Data Sources. You will see one entry per data source. Configure each appropriately.

Comment: How to configure multiple datasources to single report? Can you please suggest the steps?

Comment: You add data sources to a report in BIDS. Open a report in BIDS, right-click the Data Sources folder in the Report Data pane (Ctrl-Alt-D), and choose Add Data Source...

Comment: Thanks R. Richards for response but is it possible to have same functionality in report manager(Not in BIDS) where we deploy the report?

Comment: What tool are you using to *build* reports? You cannot build reports with Report Manager, that is for hosting and distributing of reports.

Comment: You are correct.But I have already created report with the help of BIDS which have multiple data sources and now I want to deploy it in report manager by upload file option(as I mentioned in question), so is there any way to set multiple data sources to a report in report manager?

Comment: Just upload/deploy the report to Report Manager, the data sources used in the RDL will be there afterward.

Comment: I am not allowed to directly deploy the report from BIDS, that's the problem. I have only one option to deploy the report that is Upload File.

Comment: When you have completed uploading the RDL to report manager, have you looked at it's properties to see the Data Sources? Have you tried to manage them there?

Comment: Yes but currently I am able to assign only one data source to a report. Do I missing any settings over here?